# Internet unstable, even with two WANs and a load balancer

Tags: load-balancing

I run a small business with 5 to 10 computers. We have two optic fiber links plugged into a TP-Link TL-ER605 load balancer. There are 4 Tenda MW6 Mesh routers spread across our place to distribute wifi, plus two computers that are connected through CAT5 cables to the load balancer itself.

The problem is, the Internet is quite unstable. I quite often have to reboot everything manually. But my guess is there's something misconfigured for the load balancer because if I go to the load balancer admin panel I can see both connections working just fine.

[image]
[image]

Can anyone please advise on this?

Comment: Without any logs of what's happening, only a (subjective) description that *Internet is unstable*? No, we can't. Sorry.

Comment: What have you tried to debug this? Reduce it to the minimum number of components that reproduce the problem. e.g. just one of the direct wired computers to test (which removes the wifi as a variable). Then disconnect one of the WAN connections. Also how is the Load Balancer configured? Is it using one WAN as backup or is it distributing load across both WAN links (if so how, what algorithm is it using?)